# Django - how to fix ModelForm CharField doesn't appear in template page?

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have a ModelForm where one of the fields is set like this:

```
group_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'float-none', 'pattern':'^[a-zA-Z\d-_]*$', 'style':'width:140px;'}), required=False)
```

Now when I started the server in development environment, everything works, and the input field appears as it should in the template page.

After pushed the code to production environment, and starting the server, this field doesn't appear at all in the template page, though I do see it in the code where it should appear.

What can be causing this to happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post entire ModelForm class? There should be Meta class inside with ```fields``` attribute which states what fields should be used by the form. If ```group_name``` is not stated inside the ```fields``` attribute then it won't be displayed properly. More details can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

Comment: I checked that, it has only one field-name inside fields attribute, however, despite what's written in Meta class it still presents all other fields that appear in the form except the new one I added.